# What does `configurations.<config>` allow to iterate over?

Tags: groovy, gradle

In the [gradle documentation](https://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/writing_build_scripts.html#N10AF5) in the section about groovy basic, we have an example:

```
configurations.runtime.each { File f -> println f }
```

What the code was supposed to print? I write the simple build script containig this line:

```
apply plugin: 'java'

configurations.runtime.each { File f -> println f }

dependencies{
    project(':api') //This's just a project declared in the settings.gradle
}
```

and what the `gradle check` does is print nothing. What does it mean actually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general this will iterate over all files resolved for the specified configuration. In your case this configuration is `runtime`. As you havn't declared any runtime dependencies,  no file is printed. Vahid is right that you should put this kind of statements into a task, otherwise it will be called at gradles configuration time on every build invocation, even when just asking for available tasks via "gradle tasks".

Answer (score 1):

you should overwrite gradle check method:

```
check << {
    configurations.runtime.each { File f -> println f }
}
```

then run

```
gradle check
```

Comment: the print there will run always (regardless of task), but there is just nothing to iterate over and therefor to print.  add just `println "hello"` and you will see

Comment: technically, you don't "override" the check task, but add an action to it. the check task is a "lifecycle" task which has no action per default